# MVP and data loading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-mvp

The code I will quote is from an app that is quite similar to [googlecodelabs/android-testing](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing).

For a number of reasons, We want to follow the MVP pattern, so we want to respect the dependency inversion principle and never make the Presenter know about activities, fragments, or any context-related objects.

At the same time, we want the View to remain as dumb as possible, by only forwarding user interactions to the presenter that will be in charge of eventually updating the View.

So a classic scenario is when the user presses re-load button, the View forwards the event to the presenter, the presenter will make a call to the Model to get new data and passes it back to the View via some kind of `.showStuff(stuff)` callback.

The question is: how do you handle multi-threading in this? The Model is gonna make a network call and you don't want (you even can't) do this on the UI Thread.

What I do, but I'm not sure it's a good way (brings some ugliness and boilerplate) is make all event reporting (calls from the View to the Presenter) run on a separate thread (creating a new thread each time, isn't that a bad practice?) :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_articles);
    mPresenter = new ArticlesPresenter(this, Injector.provideArticlesRepository());

    new Thread(() -> {
        mPresenter.loadArticles(true);
    }).start();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        mPresenter.loadArticle(articleId);
    }).start();
}
```

And since callbacks from Presenter will now come from a non-Ui thread, we need to make sure all UI updating run on UI Thread :

```
@Override
public void setProgressIndicator(boolean active) {
    runOnUiThread(() -> {
        Log.i(TAG, "set progress indicator : "+active);
        Toast.makeText(this, "progress indicator: "+active, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

}

@Override
public void showArticles(Map<String, List<Article>> articles) {
    runOnUiThread(() -> {
        Log.i(TAG, "show articles, keys: " + articles.keySet());
        Toast.makeText(this, "show all articles", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
}
```

I tried it and it works, but I think we can do better. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `ReactiveX/RxJava` for this, <s>that way you won't have to deal with any callbacks</s>. You would simply return some sort of `Observable` from your model containing all your data, which your presenter then would subscribe to. Using `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` will ensure all work is done in the appropriate threads.

Edit:

Actually, I mispoke. Your view would still receive callbacks from your presenter, but you won't have to worry about them being outside of the `UI` thread.

Comment: What about LiveData?
But the need is to trigger a reload each time the user asks for it, instead of keeping an eye on a distant database.
What might be a good idea is downloading Articles from the network each time the user asks for a reload, then pushing them to a local DB from which the UI already has a LiveData (Observable). But a local db is too much for what I'm trying to keep simple ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can do better, but you have to use something else instead of `Thread`. I think best options now are

1. `RxJava2`
2. Kotlin `Coroutines` (if you use kotlin)

Both cases rid you from possible callback hell and from calling runOnUiThread

Answer (score 1):

You are actually quite correct. Effectively to achieve what you describe does require boilerplate (runOnUi) and spawning threads (I would suggest a Cached Thread Pool executor) - typically in the model.

I experimented with and developed an approach around this which I wrote about here: [Simple MVP for Android](https://notesofapragmaticprogrammer.wordpress.com/2017/04/06/building-a-simple-mvp-android-app-from-the-ground-up/), but the boilerplate and restoring view state proved such a pain that I ended up developing a framework which I have made available here:[UCS Framework](https://github.com/cjsoftware-lib/ucsFramework).

The SMVP framework is quite close to what you are talking about, but the UCS framework might be of more interest to you. It uses annotation processors to manage the threading automatically and eliminate as much of the boilerplate as possible. It's still in progress and not perfect, but you might find it very interesting. I should add that both approaches are designed to survive rotation ;-)